# C program that calculates number of days between two dates

Tags: c, algorithm

I have written a C program that calculates number of days between two dates. Unfortunately, it doesn't compile properly. I don't know why. Can someone please help me fix the code? It seems like there is some issue with SCANF and PRINTF functions. I don't even get a chance to input my own date.

This is the output that I get: 
Illegal date
-1607965827

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int days_in_month[13] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

struct date {
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
};

int leap_year(int year) {
    if(year%400==0) return 1;

    if(year%4==0 && year%100!=0) return 1;

    return 0;
}

int correct(struct date d) {
    if(d.day < 1 || d.day > days_in_month[d.month]) return 0;

    if(d.month < 1 || d.month > 12) return 0;

    return 1;
}

int number_of_days(struct date d) {
    int result = 0;
    int i;

    for(i=1; i < d.year; i++) {
        if(leap_year(i))
            result += 366;
        else
            result += 365;
    }

    for(i=1; i < d.month; i++) {
        result += days_in_month[i];

        if(leap_year(d.year) && i == 2) result++;
    }

    result += d.day;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    struct date first, second;
    int days;

    scanf("%d %d %d", first.day, first.month, first.year);
    scanf("%d %d %d", second.day, second.month, second.year);

    if(!correct(first) || !correct(second)) {
        printf("Illegal date\n");
    }

    days = number_of_days(first) - number_of_days(second);

    printf("%d", days);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your usage of `scanf` is wrong. Pass pointers to tell where to read the data.

Comment: Is your program misbehaving when you run it? If you're able to run it at all, it compiled properly.

Comment: I don't see any C++ in your code.

Comment: Why the C++ tag, for a C question??

Comment: also `correct` does not consider the leap years. e.g input `29 2 2016`

Comment: Any issues still not addressed by the answers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the addresses of arguments passed to scanf (use &)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:-
1. In main(), first.day is the name of the variable, rather we have to pass the       reference(address) of the variable in the scanf("%d", &first.day);

2.Your days might be negative if(second date is greater than the first), you sure can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect usage of `scanf()`.  `%d` expects a matching `int *`, not an `int`.  Also, always check the return value of input functions.  You will save time.  Unless the return code is as expected, do not trust inputs like `first.day`  to hopefully be given valid values.  [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4062354/mikecat)

A good compile warns about mis-matched formats.  Either enable all compiler warnings or get a new compiler.

```
// scanf("%d %d %d", first.day, first.month, first.year);
if (scanf("%d %d %d", &first.day, &first.month, &first.year) != 3) {
  puts("Bad input");
  return -1;
}
```

Other issues include:

`days_in_month[d.month])` does not consider leap years. @BLUEPIXY
`int main()` not portable/correct - use `int`main(void)`.

Minor stuff:
`leap_year()`, issues with years before  1582. Could add year test in `correct()`.  `if (year > 1582) good();`
`int` range may be insufficient for day number, use `long`.
`for(i=1; i < d.year; i++)` is inefficient.
Avoid magic numbers like `i == 2`
More common to pass structures by address than value.
`"%d%d%d"` will also work instead of `"%d %d %d"`

BYW: Nice use of structures.